# AVAudioRecorder prepareToRecord always return NO

Tags: objective-c, avaudiorecorder

Here's the code I am using to trigger recording. Can someone suggest solution?

`[AVAudioRecorder prepareToRecord]` always return NO

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];

NSMutableDictionary *recordSettings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
if(recordEncoding == ENC_PCM)
{
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatLinearPCM] forKey: AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey: AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];
}
else
{
    NSNumber *formatObject;

    switch (recordEncoding) {
        case (ENC_AAC):
            formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC];
            break;
        case (ENC_ALAC):
            formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless];
            break;
        case (ENC_IMA4):
            formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleIMA4];
            break;
        case (ENC_ILBC):
            formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatiLBC];
            break;
        case (ENC_ULAW):
            formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatULaw];
            break;
        default:
            formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleIMA4];
    }

    [recordSettings setObject:formatObject forKey: AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey: AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:12800] forKey:AVEncoderBitRateKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityHigh] forKey: AVEncoderAudioQualityKey];
}

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/recordTest.caf", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

NSError *error = nil;
audioRecorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:recordSettings error:&error];

BOOL canRecord = [audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
if ([audioRecorder prepareToRecord] == YES){
    [audioRecorder record];
}else {
    int errorCode = CFSwapInt32HostToBig ([error code]);
    NSLog(@"Error: %@ [%4.4s])" , [error localizedDescription], (char*)&errorCode);
}
```

Comment: 1) Can you check that `audioRecorder` isn't nil? 2) You're calling `prepareToRecord` twice.

Comment: Actually I am checking bool value return by prepareToRecord I think that is no big deal.

Comment: Can you tell the difference between `audioRecorder` being `nil` and `prepareToRecord` returning `NO`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to activate the `AVAudioSession`:

```
[audioSession setActive:YES error:&error];
```

Comment: in my case audioSession setActive always return No, with null error description

Comment: Is audioSession nil?

Comment: yes, but I've found that the problem was with my device mic that's why audioSession was not started